# How to add ajax control in the project

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net using C#.I want to add Ajax Control to my Web Pages.I am using visual studio 2005.That had ajax basic control not extended control and bin folder contain ajax controltoolkit.dll.But when I am adding control to my page,it shows the unknown elements.I add references and select that file(dll).Still the  assembly details is not coming in my aspx page.And still saying unknown element.I have another project also.In that I done same ,and it works also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit your web.config

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
```

Goes between

```
<assemblies></assemblies>
```

tag.

```
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
```

Goes between

```
 <controls></controls>
```

tag.

Comment: I solved my problem in another way.I had scriptmanager and update pannel in aspx page.And scriptmanager was in my master page.I opened master page aspx and cs file.If there is script manager in master page just add updatepanel in aspx page.Don't necessary to add script manager in aspx page.